# Can't convert time object to datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My main aim is to find out the total hours it took for individual jobs. I did try to minus the two time columns but got an error: `<class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`.

I ran the .info() and saw the time columns were objects. In the excel file the format is time only not a date time format. I tried converting the first time column to a datetime format and this is the result:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C:/users/paul/desktop/data project/July.xls', index_col=0)
hrs_st = (pd.to_datetime(df['AST'].str.strip(), format='%H:%M:%S'))
print (hrs_st)
```

Work Order

```
BAEBRO-906063           NaT
BAEBRO-906191           NaT
BAEBRO-906207           NaT
BAEBRO-906079           NaT
BAEBRO-906095           NaT
BAEBRO-906159           NaT
...
```

Comment: What does the column look like before you try the conversion?

Comment: Work Order                     
BAEBRO-906063          06:46:03
BAEBRO-906191          06:46:03
BAEBRO-906207          06:46:03
BAEBRO-906079          06:46:03
BAEBRO-906095          06:46:03
BAEBRO-906159          06:46:03
BAEBRO-906175          06:46:03
BAEBRO-906111          06:46:03
BAEBRO-906143          06:46:03
BAEBRO-906127          06:46:03
BAEBRO-898690          06:27:41
BAEBRO-914546          08:35:00
BAEBRO-891130          08:00:00
BAEBRO-914693          08:30:00
BAEBRO-891122          08:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit confusing to be honest. Could you be a little more specific about what is you main goal and give more information about how date is shown in you excel file.

---

second edit*
| I tried to comment what I'm writing in code.

---

I made a similar example just to understand how can I help you.

This is how my excel file looks like:

[image]

This is what the code looks like for reading and calculate differences in a very simple way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('dates.xlsx') #reading my excel

timeStart = [] #declaring 2 lists where I'm gonna put my records 
timeEnd = [] 

#Here I append my values from the excel to my lists
for value in df.get('col1'):
    timeStart.append(value)
for value in df.get('col2'):
    timeEnd.append(value)


#I suppose they both have the same amount of elements in list
#therefore I can iterate for the len of any list between timeStart and timeEnd
for i in range(len(timeStart)):
    #datetime.time object doesn't allow '-' operator to catch it's time difference,
    #you can calculate it like this having how much hours, minutes or seconds
    #spent working. Or you can just concatenate all 3 results to get it all.
    hours = timeEnd[i].hour - timeStart[i].hour #hours difference
    minutes = timeEnd[i].minute - timeStart[i].minute #minutes difference
    seconds = timeEnd[i].second - timeStart[i].second #second difference
    print(type(hours), type(minutes), type(seconds)) #all my results are int
    print(hours, minutes, seconds) #I can see the difference from one time to another
```

This is what I get in output:

```
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'> #Here you can see I have 3 int types
1 30 15 #read as 1 hour 30 minutes and 15 seconds
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
1 30 15
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
1 30 15
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
1 30 15
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
1 30 15
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
1 30 15
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
1 30 15
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
1 30 15
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
1 30 15
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Comment: so I have two columns first is work order which i use for the index number, then a time. In excel the format is just time no date eg. BAEBRO - 906191 06:46:03 this is the start time of a job then I have another column with the finish time, again it is in time format only in excel no date.

Comment: I edited main answer, hope it's what you needed. I tried this code and it works(if your main goal is to calculate difference between time and time).

Comment: Unfortunately this code did not work I got this error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'hour' in line 18 hours = timeEnd[i].hour - timeStart[i].hour #hours difference

Comment: There are no float objects in this code, be carefuL. However I'm looking forward to help you on this. If you need to be guided on this script go on my profile there is my name on discord in description. Add me and I'll help you finish this script.

Comment: This does work thanks,  I do get negative times. but that is due to the time logged against an work order has been logged incorrect for example start time was 2:32:08 PM but finish time 10:37:17 AM. The earliest start time and latest finish time should be 07:30:00 AM - 16:00:00 PM. The best thing would be to remove these errors, even though this will not show a true reflection of total time worked in a month period.

Comment: confirm it as an answer, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a better solution that works great for my original problem, which was to work out the total time taken to complete a work order. this solution helps over come excel time format which is a object type. Once converted to datetime[64] enabled minus one column by another straight forward.

`import pandas as pd
from datetime import time
from datetime import timedelta`

`df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Nativ_Zero/Desktop/work data/July.xls', index_col =0)`

`df_work = df[['WorkType', 'AST','AFT']]`

`#to convert time format column which is an object to datetime[64
df_work['AFT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_work['AFT'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
df_work['AST'] = pd.to_datetime(df_work['AST'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')`

`rm_work = df_work[df_work.WorkType == 'RM']`

`hrs_ft = rm_work['AFT']
 hrs_st = rm_work['AST']`

`hrs_t = hrs_ft - hrs_st`

```
Print(hrs_t)
```